# Dynamic column width with handsontable

Tags: handsontable

I'm using handsontable and my grids are dynamics. I'm creating them by pushing the data from a XML file. So, the content of the columns are always differents and I want that the width of that columns are defined with the content of the existing cells. If the column contains just "Parley", I want a short width and if I have "One Ring to rule them all", the width should increase.

How should I do please ?

**EDIT :**

I tried to add : `autoColumnSize : true` and it works at the beginning, but if I enter a value in a cell, every cells are shrinking.

Before :

[image]

After :

[image]

And this is the options I use to declare my hot :

```
var hot_itk = new Handsontable(container, {
        data: data_itk,         
        minSpareRows: 1,
        autoColumnSize : true,
        observeChanges : true,
        columnSorting : true,
        rowHeaders: false,
        colHeaders: false,
        contextMenu: true,
        height: 550,
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `stretchH: all` option?

```
var hot_itk = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: data_itk,         
    minSpareRows: 1,
    autoColumnSize : true,
    stretchH: 'all',
    ...
```

This stretches the table to the container's width.